# MySQL SUM of one column, Take only one of the same fields

Tags: mysql

Take a total for one column, but only need to take one row for the duplicate

```
+---------------------------+--------+
| orderId     | amount               |
+---------------------------+--------+
| 2           |   2000               |
| 2           |   2000               |
| 5           |   2000               |
| 7           |   5000               |
+---------------------------+--------+
```

I hope to get a total of 9000 instead of 11000

I want the total value of different orderIds, not the total value of the same orderId, so I can't use group by.

Comment: Where's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: not on the post, but probably on his database

Comment: @MohammedShafeek the duplicate you propose has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: @Trree what happens if there are 2 rows with: 2, 1000 and 2, 2000?

Answer (score -1):

Using `MAX(amount)` with `GROUP BY` will avoid the duplicate entries, then `SUM()` will return the expected result:

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) AS SumAmount 
FROM (
    SELECT orderId, MAX(amount) AS Amount
    FROM TableName
    GROUP BY orderId
) A
```

Please find the working demo on [**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=57523b811536a780ae63a3ba077e58e5)

Comment: @Jean-CharlesLUC OP request is _Take only one of the same fields_, so when orderId 5 entry is 3000, we need to include for the  SUM. In that case your query HAVING COUNT will fail

Comment: His post is confusing, now I have no idea of what he wants

Answer (score -1):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then `ROW_NUMBER` provides one option here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY orderId ORDER BY orderId) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT SUM(amount)
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

The ordering used by `ROW_NUMBER` above is arbitrary, but this is a good general approach in case you want to use different logic later on regarding which of the duplicate records to include in the sum.

Comment: I disagree. A primary key is a prerequisite for any relational table (which, by definition, is any table in an RDBMS)

Answer (score -1):

SELECT SUM(Amount) AS SumAmount FROM TablName where orderid = ( SELECT Distinct(orderId) FROM TableName )

I have corrected the query

Comment: Your query will retrun the wrong result. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6f02f58f177a4df02f26049dfef0a172)

Answer (score -1):

I think the best query would be

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) AS SumAmount,  COUNT(orderId)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY orderId
HAVING COUNT(orderId) > 1;
```